# Return last entry by month

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to get the last value of each month of the year, but when I enter other dates from different ages the result doesn't match, it gets just the value from the last month.

[Worksheet Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IV0KB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that

- I understand your requirement correctly
- you don't actually want to try to calculate the value on the last day of a month for which you have no data (`E8` & `E9`)

then you can use the formula below

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$16,MATCH(EOMONTH(E4,0),$A$1:$A$16))
```

[image: Screenshot illustrating proposed formula]

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. It's all correct, that's what I wanted! Thank you!